# Inverting a match operation in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am interested in reconstructing the original vector, based on its index-element decomposition. For example, suppose that I have the following vector of strings:

```
v <- c( "a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "c" )
```

Adopting [the question about matching all occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947086/how-do-i-match-all-occurrences-in-r), we can decompose this vector into its index-element pairing as follows:

```
library( tidyverse )
dcomp <- set_names(letters[1:3]) %>% map( ~which(v==.x) )
# $a
# [1] 1 2 6
#
# $b
# [1] 3 5
#
# $c
# [1] 4 7
```

I am looking for an elegant way to reverse this operation and reconstruct the original vector `v` from `dcomp`. The most straight-forward solution of using a loop requires pre-initialization of the results container and doesn't play nicely with dplyr-style piping via `%>%`:

```
## BAD SOLUTION #1
u <- c()
for( i in names(dcomp) )
  u[ dcomp[[i]] ] <- i
all( u == v )  ## TRUE
```

Using `purrr::iwalk` **does** play nicely with the `%>%` pipe, but it still requires pre-initializing `u` and using the often-chastised `<<-` (otherwise `u` assignment is not visible outside of the environment where the formula gets evaluated).

```
## BAD SOLUTION #2
u <- c()
dcomp %>% iwalk( ~(u[.x] <<- .y) )
all( u == v )  ## TRUE
```

Is there a way to construct the result "on the fly" using a pre-specified mapping of elements to indices, in a way that integrates well with `%>%` piping? The structure of `dcomp` is allowed to be changed as long as it preserves the mapping.

Comment: Wow, three answers within 7 seconds ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `stack` and then `arrange` the `data.frame` and extract the column we need:

```
stack(dcomp) %>% arrange(values) %>% .$ind
```

And if you want to get rid of those factor levels:

```
stack(dcomp) %>% arrange(values) %>% .$ind %>% as.character
```

Comment: I think `as.character` can be avoided if we use `reshape2::melt` in place of `stack`: `reshape2::melt(dcomp) %>% arrange(value) %>% .$L1`

Answer (score 4):

How about something like

```
rep(names(dcomp), lengths(dcomp))[order(unlist(dcomp))]
```

make it a function like

```
reconstruct <- function(x) rep(names(x), lengths(x))[order(unlist(x))]
dcomp %>% reconstruct()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, MrFlick. I like both your solution and the one from @bouncyball. I ended up going with the latter, because it felt a little more dplyr-esque. My initial approach defined a function around "BAD SOLUTION #1", and I wanted to see if it could be done without a `function` wrapper.